# Stdlib synonym to my zipWithMap function?

Tags: haskell

I often find myself looking to use a function like:

```
zipWithMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
zipWithMap f xs = zip xs $ map f xs
```

Such that:

```
zipWithMap (+3) [1..4] = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
```

I find myself looking for this so often, in fact, that I fear I am either reinventing the wheel or using an idiom so poorly-suited to Haskell that Real Programmers have moved away from it, thus its exclusion from stdlib.

[Hoogle gives me nothing with that type signature](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+b)+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B(a%2C+b)%5D), so I'm forced to ask: is there a more idiomatic approach? Perhaps with Arrows?

```
zipWithMap f = map $ id &&& f
```

though I'm not sure that's any better than the (subjectively) simpler style above.

Comment: I think `map (id &&& f)` is simple enough and short enough that it doesn't need its own name.

Comment: Agreed, although I personally wish that the Prelude contained (the equivalent) `fanout f g x = (f x, g x)`, which appears frequently in Bird's work. That would make this `map . fanout id`.

Comment: `zip <*> map f`.

Comment: @WillNess Although I find that Applicative version neater than the arrows one, I believe it doesn’t optimize as well.

Comment: @HTNW hmm, indeed. too bad, huh.

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
Data.Tuple.Extra>  map (second (+3) . dupe) [1..4]
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,7)]
```